# É gramaticalmente correto dizer «Queres para eu comprar?»?

Tags: gramática, orações-subordinadas

Estava eu a almoçar e ouço a seguinte conversa:

> —Compra esse tacho e experimenta, se for bom eu depois compro também. Ou ***queres para eu comprar?***

Isto no sentido de *Ou queres que eu compre? [E experimento eu.]*. De referir que o falante é de São Tomé e Príncipe.

Comment: Em Angola, a expressão "queres para eu comprar?" está correcta.

Comment: Eu não sei se é gramatical ou não, mas tenho amigos nordestinos (brasileiros) que falam algo semelhante: "quer para eu comprar?" (o uso da 2ª pessoa não é comum por estas bandas)

Comment: Não é gramatical em português Ibérico ou brasileiro "normal". São Tomé e Príncipe é como Cabe Verde e os Açores, nessas ilhas se falam dialetos do português e também existe o nível de escolaridade do falante. Neste caso, me parece que poderia ser o nível de escolaridade. Comparando com o resto do trecho, acho que dar para julgá-lo assim.

Comment: @Lambie a pessoa em causa tem graduação superior, acho que esse caso não se aplica. Eu fiquei na dúvida se é erro regional ou se é aceite como gramatical.

Comment: Parecia mas nao estava. O verbo querer está conjugado na primeira pessoa do singular, formando um predicado válido. Dando uma segunda olhada se calhar até diria que é uma frase válida, por isso é mesmo melhor que alguém de uma resposta que nao eu.

Comment: Que eu saiba, "querer para" não é uma forma corrente em português. Queres que [eu va] para comprar, até daria. É possível também que fosse um desses erros que a gente faz falando. As vezes sai um troço sem querer. Isso é uma das carasterísticas de linguagem falada . Fica uma o outra coisinha meia esquisita. Nunca aconteceu isso com vocês?? :) Comigo acontece o tempo todo. Talvez o /eu va/ficou escamoteado.

Comment: Talvez seja um regionalismo.  Em uma resposta deletada alguém disse que é gramatical em Angola.  No Brasil, como citado, não faz sentido.  Mas nós todos sabemos que a língua portuguesa não é falada só no Brasil e em Portugal.

Comment: @Centaurus mas não há concordâncias que têm de ser respeitadas? Na resposta, que passei para comentário, disse que está correcto mas sem nenhuma fonte.

Comment: @Lambie isso também tenho a certeza que não, a pessoa em causa diz isso com frequência. Até foi por isso que vim perguntar, porque me mete muita impressão.

Comment: @JorgeB As possibilidades estão minorando-se: ou ele simplesmente não sabe suster o discurso  ou vem encima de alguma estrutura usada na ilha. :) Eu traduzi uns tempos atrás vários documentos do país, todos em um portugues de Portugal bem bonitinho tanto que me entrego. Já não sei mesmo. :)

Comment: Gente, não sendo falante nativo eu estou interessado nessa pergunta mas ainda não tenho claro. Eu só posso dizer que eu entendi a expressão sem precisar explicação e a verdade é que soa natural, paralela à estrutura de (por exemplo) *Ela disse para eu comprar*. Fora isso, se os falantes usam uma forma de discurso consistentemente, então a forma é gramatical, não é?

Comment: Eu acho que o tag deveria ser "português-africano" ou mesmo "português-santomense" (África é muito grande); afinal os tags correspondentes são "português-europeu/brasileiro", não "dialeto..." E não podes **pedir para a pessoa vir aqui responder**.

Comment: @Jacinto se a pessoa soubesse responder a isso eu já lhe tinha dito, ele até tem conta num dos sites.

Comment: Não sabe dizer se esse tipo de frase é comum em São Tomé?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A frase não é gramatical na língua padrão em Portugal e pelos vistos no Brasil também não. De acordo com a *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian (Lisboa, 2013, vol. II, p. 1927-34), existem vários verbos que admitem complementos diretos oracionais infinitivos (como o da frase em questão), mas introduzidos por *para*, só mesmo os verbos diretivos, como *dizer, implorar, insistir* e *pedir*; nesse caso o infinitivo é flexionado. Exemplos meus:

> **Ele pede** *para eu comprar um tacho?* [= *que eu come um tacho.*]
>
> **Ela disse** *para tu comprares um tacho.* [= *que tu compres um tacho.*]

Os verbos *dizer, pedir* e *querer* pedem um complemento direto: *dizer/pedir/querer algo*. Nestes exemplos o complemento direto, a itálico, é uma oração com o verbo no infinitivo; daí a *Gramática* lhe chamar “complemento direto oracional infinitivo”.

O verbo *querer* admite complemento direto oracional infinitivo (não flexionado), mas não introduzido por *para*, como em (exemplos da *Gramática*, p. 1933-4):

> (93) a. Os professores querem/desejam *negociar um salário melhor*.
>
> […]
>
> (94) a. O cozinheiro quer *ser ele a decorar a travessa*.

A *Gramatica do Português* é uma gramática descritiva baseada primeiramente no português europeu. É fácil de ver que estas conclusões se aplicam também à língua escrita no Brasil. Procurei no  [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/hist-gen/) e encontro na literatura e imprensa brasileiras, tal como nas portuguesas, exemplos destes complementos diretos oracionais infinitivos introduzidos por *para* com verbos diretivos; nas não encontrei nem um com *querer*. (Procurei “[querer] para eu”, que busca todas as flexões de *querer*, e repeti com *tu, ele, você*, etc.) Agora, isto não elimina a possibilidade de esta estrutura com *querer* ser aceitável, pelo menos coloquialmente, em São Tomé ou outros países.

Answer (score 0):

Só seria aceitável se o significado fosse: Queres o tacho que eu pago?
De outra forma o correto no contexto seria "Queres que compre para experimentar?"